# Grails : Only Child Domain should be persistant in database

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have following structure in Grails

```
class User {
   //fields
    static mapping = {tablePerHierarchy = false}
}

class Employee extends User {
//insert code here
}
```

When I run code at the time of saving employee details user is also saved in user table.

now my requirement is if user is already added in database then user should not be added again
if not available then user entry should be done in user table.

i m trying but all time user is added in user table.

please help me in second case when user is already available then it should not be added in table

Comment: One issue is that `tablePerHierarchy = false` should be `tablePerHierarchy false`

Comment: I tried but still no change...

Comment: First check in your db if are present two tables, user and employee table. If exist table per sub-class is working right. So if the two table exisit your problem is in the code you wrote for create a new Employee starting from an existing User.